# Back-EMF related question

Tags: power-engineering, electrical

[image]If a circular dipolar magnet is set to roll down an incline through an array of coils set out as found in a bicycle dynamo – one above and one below per set, but linearly along the incline.  Arranged so as the magnet poles roll perpendicular to each coil (set) centre down along the array, would the back-EMF once speed increases stop the magnet from rolling?

Comment: Draw it, please. If there *is* a back-EMF generated in this scenario, yes, it will slow it down.

Comment: I'm new to this, but the full extent of the problem is show in a picture synopsis under Andy1 in sustainable living.  are you able to access it? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. But the questions on SE should be self contained, and have all of the information required to understand it without the need to go to external links.

Comment: The question there is 'Getting power form an innovative new mechanism'.

Comment: But if it is another *perpetuum mobile*, don't waste your and our time.

Comment: It is far from perpetual motion drivel, I'm trying to identify to resistance/s that will be incurred in a given EMF arrangement.

Comment: Great. Then back to my first suggestion - put all of the information in the question.

Comment: Draw it please!

Comment: As stated I am finding my way. How do I post an image?

Comment: There should be a picture now available, it is the last section/s that I'm attempting to clarify. Thanks

Comment: So.. what is the purpose of this device?

Comment: To charge say, a mobile?

Comment: No, I mean standalone? What does it do? Storing energy?

Comment: It generates an electrical output, hopefully, from the rotational energy of the mechanical machine.  Of course the depends on whether that depends on if the back-EMF will prevent it from doing so.

Comment: So it is converting mechanical energy to electrical? A generator/dynamo? Obviously if it is loaded on the electrical side, it will load the mechanical side as well. The more electricity you consume the more mechanical energy to be put in. I am still not convinced we are talking about the same thing, though...

Comment: cross-posted, here: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6102/3293 ; @Andy, we expect apologies once you understand why you are wrong. It could be a good exercise to you to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

> would the back-EMF once speed increases stop the magnet from rolling?

Firstly, it's not a back-emf but an induced voltage.

So, if the array of coils were not connected to a load i.e. they were not generating any current from the induced emf then no, the magnet would not be impeded by the presence of the coils.

If current is being drawn from the coils then energy is being taken from the magnet and it will slow down and reach a lower speed.

Comment: Thank you.  Would there be any 'motor effect' to take into consideration?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "motor effect".

Comment: Once the coil is induced and current flows, the induced magnetic field around the coil would be the same polarity and repel the magnet out in the direction it is rolling (from MDC)?

Comment: The magnetic field doesn't like to be induced. And it will do everything to prevent/reduce the change in itself.

Comment: Could you elaborate please

Comment: A change in a magnetic field will cause an effect in anything around it to produce the "counter-change", I.e. to induce the change in the opposite direction.

Comment: And this would 'out-weigh' the GPE of the magnet down the incline?

Comment: Of course it won't. Only if we are talking about superconductors and ideal environment. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWTSzBWEsms

Comment: Final question.  Therefore the concept as shown in the picture synopsis would work, but at a reduced speed and depending on the weight of the mass (magnet)?

Comment: @Andy the speed of the magnet will induce a voltage and if the coil is shorted, the secondary magnetic field will attempt to repel the magnet but some of that current flowing in the coil causes heat loss due to the non-zero electrical resistance of the coil and this is a loss of energy so total repulsion is not possible and the magnet slows but does not stop.

Comment: It must each an equilibrium speed because if it stopped rolling there wouldn't be any induced current, so nothing to oppose motion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when a magnet passes by a coil of wire or other conductor, even when no physical object touches the magnet, there is a physical force that opposes the motion of the magnet.

This force is generally taken for granted in the normal operation of [alternators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternator) such as [car alternators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternator_(automotive)) and the other kinds of [electric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator) that move a magnet past a stationary coil of wire.
There's a certain amount of mechanical energy going into the generator -- often measured as force times distance, or torque times rotations.
When there is nothing connected to the output wires of a generator, it's generally very easy to keep the thing spinning -- the no-load mechanical power.
When we hook up, to those wires, light bulbs or cell phone chargers or some other device that uses up electrical power, it takes far more mechanical power to keep the thing spinning -- there's a physical force that reaches through the apparently empty space between the copper and the magnets, and pushes back on the magnets.

We often think of the generator as dividing the input mechanical power into two parts -- one part gets converted to electrical energy, and the other part is lost ("wasted") by friction, eddy currents, and otherwise dissipated.
People who design generators try to minimize this wasted power.
A well-designed generator can convert over 95% of the input mechanical power into output electrical power.

- [Lenz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law)
- [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force)
- [Force between magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets)
- [Dropping a magnet through a copper tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdycXbVWF9A)  (thanks,  Eugene Sh.)
- [eddy current brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake)

(FIXME: Is there a name for this physical force on the magnet?
I thought it was the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), but a quick search to refresh my memory seems to indicate that is the equal and opposite force on the electrons in the copper due to the magnetic fields from the magnet).

The slow-down in this electric generator is caused by that magnetic force (which can be measured in Newtons), and has nothing to do with what is commonly called back-EMF. The back-EMF which is a phenomenon that occurs in electric motors and is measured in Volts, and (confusingly) is not a mechanical force.

Answer (score 1):

Even without a drawing, since your description is vague to the extreme, it would not stop the magnet.

Properly arranged it will impede the magnet and act as a brake, but it will only slow the magnet to a fixed speed, assuming the coils are shorted or attached to some load.

If the magnet WERE to stop, there would be zero back-EMF and therefore no braking force, so it would start to move under gravity again.

BTW.. you don't even need coils. An [eddy current brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake) works with just a metal plate. But again, it only impedes motion and brake force is proportional to speed of the magnet.

[image]

Comment: I find this demonstration pretty convincing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdycXbVWF9A

Comment: I'm a product designer specialising in eco design and was a car mechanic ...sadly I find electrical engineering extremely tricky, hence the request for clarification.